# Scanner layout Zxing

Tags: android, zxing

Anybody knows how can I customize the scanner layout in Zxing library? I want to modify the width of the scanner, I try in capture.xml but i can´t. Anybody knows or there is a manual?

Thank you

Comment: The layout is defined by capture.xml. what do you mean you can't change it ?

Comment: Thanks, and how can I change the width of the scanner visor?

Comment: I want to know how can I change the scanning rectangle´s width and height, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I explained how to do it in this post: https://medium.com/@marta/bar-code-scanner-in-android-with-custom-layout-zxing-2ab92d9d744c

In Short:

- Add required AAR dependencies in Gradle (https://github.com/embarkmobile/zxing-android-minimal#adding-aar-dependency-with-gradle)
- Provide a custom layout for the capture activity. See sample/src/main/res/layout/custom_capture_layout.xml for examples.
- Set up the Scanner in your Java code:

  IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
  integrator.setCaptureLayout(R.layout.custom_layout);
  integrator.initiateScan();
- For a cancel/back button, use the ids @id/zxing_back_button for zxing-android-minimal.

Comment: Hi, can you help me with my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728424/zxing-custom-scanner-layout-and-button)?

Comment: 'setCaptureLayout' method is no longer available!

Answer (score 0):

Try Include the capture layout in your xml file.

```
           <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/frame_scan"
                    android:layout_width="150dip"
                    android:layout_height="100dip"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

                    <include layout="@layout/capture" />
                </FrameLayout>
```

And Extend the Capture Activity from Zxing's Library. 
Thats it, You are good to go.

```
 public class ScanCard extends CaptureActivity {

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.scan_card);
}


    @Override
    public void handleDecode(Result rawResult, Bitmap barcode) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.handleDecode(rawResult, barcode);

        Toast.makeText(
                ScanCard.this,
                "Results : "
                        + rawResult.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();


    }
 }
```

Good Luck, Please feel free to ask if you have any clarification.It's working for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "unable to extend CaptureActivity"? You are getting any error?

Comment: maybe you should delete your comment? (the person you were responding too apparently did so)

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question, the dimensions of the rectangle of the scanner can change in CameraManager inside the package com.google.zxing.client.android.camera